# jQuery function running multiple times on each click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the below functions as a part of JS.

`_RenderVendorView` will trigger when clicking on a row of the table of vendors and it will show vendor details page,
And in vendor details view page there is a button with class `.vendorsListButton`, which will go back to table of vendors, means will trigger `_RenderVendorsList`

```
    var _RenderVendorsList = function () {

        $(document).on('click', '.vendorsListButton', function () {     
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "/purchases/render_vendors_list",
                type: "POST",
                success:function(data){
                    $data = $(data); // the HTML content that controller has produced
                    $('#vendorcontainer').hide().html($data).fadeIn();
                    _TableVendors();
                    _RenderVendorForm();
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

```
    var _RenderVendorView = function () {

        $(document).on('click', '#tableVendors tbody td:not(:first-child)', function () { 
            if ($(this).index() == 4 ) { 
                // provide index of column in which we want prevent row click here is column of 4 index
                return;
            }
            else{
                var rowdata = $('#tableVendors').DataTable().row($(this).parents('tr') ).data();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/purchases/render_vendor_view",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {vendor:rowdata.vendor_id},
                    success:function(data){
                        $data = $(data); // the HTML content that controller has produced
                        $('#vendorcontainer').hide().html($data).fadeIn();
                        _TableBills(rowdata);
                        _TableExpenses(rowdata);
                        _RenderVendorsList();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

Now, problem is that 1st click on row open vendor page and 1st click on `.vendorsListButton` go back to vednors list,
2nd click on row also open vendor page, but when 2nd click on `.vendorsListButton` will run `_RenderVendorsList` two times, and on each iterate function run increase ...

Not sure why it running multiple times on each forth and back.

What is wrong with this loop?

Comment: This happens because you add more times an event handler.....

Comment: You are delegating event listeners to the document. That only needs to be done once. Unless you use `off()` then every time you call that function  a new event listener gets added to existing one(s)

Comment: If you're using delegated event handlers (which you are) then you want to set them up once (even before the html has been built) and then do nothing.  Don't keep recalling `_RenderVendorsList()`

Answer (score 1):

> [`.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) :  The `.off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()

You can it like :

```
$(document).off('click', '.vendorsListButton').on('click', '.vendorsListButton', function () { 
    //Your event logic here
    ...
}):
```

It will detach the event first then attach a new one what will prevent duplication.

**Better solution:**
Since you're using event delegation, you can attach the event just once and it will be working even for the newly added rows, so no need to recall `_RenderVendorsList()` every time.

So just remove the line `_RenderVendorsList();` that is inside the other event, and call it one time at the start.

Maybe like:

```
var _RenderVendorView = function () {

    _RenderVendorsList();

    $(document).on('click', '#tableVendors tbody td:not(:first-child)', function () { 
    ...
```

Comment: How about this? actually i tried ```.one``` and it works, ```$(document).one('click', '.vendorsListButton', function () ```

Comment: It will work but it's not an efficient solution, you'll still call a function and render code that you don't need, better to use `.on()` and call the function once...